# Why does this semicolon appear if I use jQuery serialize() on inputs with square brackets in the name?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, brackets

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="options_1" value="options_1" name="options[]">  
<input type="checkbox" id="options_2" value="options_2" name="options[]">  
<input type="checkbox" id="options_3" value="options_3" name="options[]">
```

I check the first two options and send it to the server via ajax in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myfile.php",
    data: {
        'options':$('input[name="options[]"]').serialize()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
           //do some stuff
    },
    success: function(msg){
        //do some stuff
    }
});
```

Firebug shows me the data that has been posted:

**options** *options%5B%5D=options_1&options%5B%5D=options_2*
So far, so good.

In myfile.php I get the POST-Variable like this:

```
$options = $_POST['options'];
```

Now when I echo $options I get this:

```
"options[]=options_1&options;[]=options_2"
```

Where does this semicolon in front of the second pair of brackets come from? This is driving me crazy.

I already used *utf8_decode* on the POST data as well as *urldecode* and *rawurldecode*. Nothing changes. I also escaped the square brackets in the ajax call like this:

```
data: {
    'options':$('input[name="options\\[\\]"]').serialize()
},
```

That didn't help either. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, and I was only able to get it to work by using ".serializeArray()", I hope this was what you were looking for.

```
data: {
    'options':$('input[name="options[]"]').serializeArray()
},
```

For me this outputs standard string in the same format as GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to remove [] from html names, it's bad design. There can be a problem on [jQuery side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72577/286114) or PHP too.
I can see no other problems in your code.

[What characters are allowed in the HTML Name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424860/what-characters-are-allowed-in-the-html-name-attribute)
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the brackets[] and the same name for each input element?
If I get you right you can serialize by a wrapping element..

```
<form id="options">
    <input type="checkbox" id="options_1" value="options_1" name="option1" />  
    <input type="checkbox" id="options_2" value="options_2" name="option2" />  
    <input type="checkbox" id="options_3" value="options_3" name="option3" />  
</form>
```

So you can serialize like

```
data: {
    'options':$('#options').serialize()
},
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. I use the same name, because then I can use "parse_str" in php which then automatically generates an array named $options. That's handy, because there are actually more checkboxes than just 3.

Comment: No, I didn't. The semicolon still appears and I have no clue why.

Comment: I can only suggest to do it in an other way then.. anyway tested it now without any problems

echo $options;
parse_str($options);
print_r($options);

gives in firebug:
__
options%5B%5D=options_1&options%5B%5D=options_2&options%5B%5D=options_3
Array
(
    [0] => options_1
    [1] => options_2
    [2] => options_3
)
__
With jquery 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read **[this](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/)** and try this:

```
data: {
        'options':$('input[name="options[]"]').replace('%5B%5D', '[]') 
    },
```

or this

```
$.param(obj, true);
```

The `true` in the `$.param` indicates the traditional method of serializing an object should be used. The traditional method does not use square brackets when it encounters the same parameter name.