# Can a HTML input name contain spaces, commas etc?

Tags: php, html, forms

Basically, can I have input names like `<input name="total sum(userID2223)" type="text" />` and similar? Are there any rules for that?

Comment: This is the answer for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13858670/362536

Comment: Why would you want to? The names relate to the fields as they appear in the document. In your example I'd use `totalsum` or something similar. If you start naming them in some way that relates them to a specific user on your system your back-end processing will become a nightmare. If you need to include user-specific data do it in a `hidden` field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  When PHP reads the form, you will be able to address the data with `$POST["total sum(userID2223)"]`.

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do I can't say for sure, but there's probably a bad design decision happening somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

It's not allowed in HTML4: From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Interestingly, it has long been common to use `[]` in `NAME` attributes, even though not allowed by the above; PHP will turn these inputs into arrays in `_$GET` and `$_POST`.

It's allowed in HTML5: From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name

> Any non-empty value for name is allowed, but the names "*charset*" and "isindex" are special

For your application, I would recommend array notation:

```
<input name="total[2223]" type="text" />
```

Then in PHP it would be `$_POST['total'][2223]`.

Comment: The `name` attribute in HTML 4 is defined as containing CDATA, not a NAME token.