# Radio buttons and $_POST

Tags: php, html

two problem i have:

first:

i want users see my form with no prechecked in radio buttons but it does when they see it at first time(as you see)(explain that i use checked to show user which radio he/she selected after pushing the button)

second:

why when i name submit button "select sex" and push it in the form, it doesn't echo "it's done" but when i name it "select" it works?! i want my submit name has two words.

and the codes:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['select sex']))
        echo "it's done";
    ?>
    <form name="input" action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="
    <?php if(isset($_POST['select sex']) and $_POST['sex']=='male') echo 'checked'; else echo '';?>
    "> Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" checked="
    <?php if(isset($_POST['select sex']) and $_POST['sex']=='female') echo 'checked'; else echo '';?>
    "> Female<br />
    <input type="submit" name="select sex" value="Submit" />
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Remove the `checked` attribute completely, you use it in a wrong way. Please read the documentation!

Comment: names should not have a space

Comment: `'sselect sex' !== "select sex"`

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan — Why not?

Comment: @Quentin check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396037/can-a-html-input-name-contain-spaces-commas-etc

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan — Only one of the answers there says it is a problem, and that answer is wrong (see my comment on that answer).

Comment: @Quentin - thanks for the note, but we can say at least it is a bad practice, because if you are sending a post array with spaced indexes which will not let you turn these indexes to variables in any case.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan — Bad practise is letting user input determine variable names. Use an (since we are talking PHP) associative array.

Comment: @Quentin, he isn't talking about user input determining variable names--he's talking about developer-determined field names determining variable names. That said, mamdouh, it would be trivial to write code that handles the space before converting it to a variable, and the concern about the spaces is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox,  not mentioned checked attribute for any of the check box option.

For submit button, normally we are not using the space in field name and this is the best practice. Though you have used then you have written the wrong code.  Please check below updated code line for if statement.

```
 if(isset($_POST['select sex']))
```