# how to strip out spaces in string

Tags: php

I am using a form in which people can order products. 
One of the variables of a product is this:

```
$product1 = 'Baguette Cheese';
```

I use this variable in the form like this:

```
<td><?php echo $product1 ?></td>
<td>&euro; <?php echo number_format($prijs[$product1], 2); ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $product1 ?>" size="3" /></td>
```

Doing it this way, i can not read the name attrib. with $_POST because there is a space between **Baguette** and **Cheese**

This does work:

```
$product1 = 'Cheese-Burger';
```

But in the first **td** there is Cheese-Burger displayed and i do not want the hyphen between it.
So i thougth: keep the hyphen away and strip the spaces in the name attrib like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $product1) ?>" size="3" /></td>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working, he can not read the $_POST.

How can i make this work without using hyphen or underscore between **Baguette** and **Cheese** ?

When submitting:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
echo $_POST[$product1]; // no result   
}
```

Comment: POST data do support spaces and hyphens ?

Comment: @adeneo, no, They need to be a single word, but can have numbers and underscores.

Comment: You're only doing 1 `str_replace`.  Meaning your are posting `$_POST['baguettechees'];` but you are reading `$_POST['baguette cheese']`!

Comment: @nuet Why are you giving the form `input name` the name of the product instead of simply `product1` ? then you can get it by using $_POST['product1']; . It  doesn't make sense the form code.

Comment: @PedroLobito - Nope, *HTML form names* can't have spaces etc. but POST data sent as x-www-form-urlencoded can have almost anything, and PHP also supports almost anything as an array key.

Comment: It's to be able to post the form back in the database with the related products + amounts I guess. He should build up the forms as `<input name="product["'.$product_id.']" />';` though

Comment: `$_POST[$product1]` doesn't make any sense, when does the  var `$product1` come from?! I guess you need to read more about forms, take a look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: Well, i am not using a database. This form is only for mailing the choosen products. The main reason i want to do it this way, is that the user of the this orderlist **only**  has to change the string and everything should be automatically changed also in the form

Comment: You should avoid making it that way, because input name have to respect a [strict format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3424964/2123530).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this is not working, he can not read the $_POST.

You aren't echoing the `str_replace`:

```
<td><input type="text" name="<?php str_replace(' ', '', $product1) ?>" size="3" /></td>
```

**Change to:**

```
<td><input type="text" name="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $product1) ?>" size="3" /></td>
```

---

Update after reading you comments:

> Why are you giving the `form` `input` `name` the name of the product instead
>   of simply `product1` ? then you can get it by using `$_POST['product1'`];
>   . It doesn't make sense the form code.

**Try this instead:**

```
<td><?php echo $product1 ?></td>
<td>&euro; <?php echo number_format($prijs[$product1], 2); ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product1" size="3" /></td>
```

then get the `$_POST` value by using:

```
$_POST['product1']
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot the echo befor it, but it is still not working. `echo $_POST[$product1];` displays nothing **Post above updated**

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
$product1 = 'Baguette Cheese';

$test = explode(" ", $product1);
```

this will produce an array:

```
["Baguette","Cheese"]
```

then:

```
$nowhitespace = $test[0] . $test[1];

or

$nowhitespace = implode("", $test);
```

Comment: downvoting because this is just a terrible solution for sthing simple as `str_replace(' ', '', $str);`

Comment: yeah fair enough...;)