# Why is this simple php form not posting?

Tags: php, forms, post

It's as simples as a form can get. However, it's not working at all.

The HTML form:

```
 <body>
    <form method="POST" action="porra.php">
         <div id="refeicao">
                <h1>Segunda</h1>
            Café da manhã
            <br><input name="Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0" type="number" min="0" placeholder="un." />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script src="gerar_cardapio_js.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

The PHP code (page "porra.php"):

```
<?php
$var = $_POST["Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0"];
?>
```

However, i get this error after submission:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Café da manhã-quantidade-0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cardapio\porra.php on line 2
```

Can someone please make this work?

**EDIT:**

I edited the code to correct a typo and to elimnate code that I was not using for this question.

Comment: input name="Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0"   deosnt have a value

Comment: I use this page to correct erros in my code. So, it expresses my anger haha

Comment: Majeebu Rahman, I made this change:

<input value="cafe" name="Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0" type="number" min="0" placeholder="un." />

But it's not working still.

Comment: Please, run `var_dump($_POST);` so you can see the keys and values...

Comment: You have to access it like this: `$_POST['Cafe_da_manhã-quantidade-0']`. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13858670/4577762). If you check the result from my previous comment, you'll see that spaces have been converted to `_` (at least when I tested it)

Comment: added an answer , please check with it...happy coding

Comment: Why don't you just use an easier variable than "Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0"? This might be making you a bit confused from your native language portuguese, to coding.

Comment: FirstOne, as suggested by many, I'm not going to use non-ascii charaters. That did it for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename the input name for example cafe-da-manha-quantidade-0 don't use space or accent character.

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action="porra.php">
     <div id="refeicao">
            <h1>Segunda</h1>
        Café da manhã
        <br><input name="cafe-da-manha-quantidade-0" type="number" min="0" placeholder="un." />
</form>
<script src="gerar_cardapio_js.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

in php use isset for don't produce warnings

```
if (isset($_POST['cafe-da-manha-quantidade-0'])) {
      $yourvar = $_POST['cafe-da-manha-quantidade-0'];
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to get the value of the first input, not second. I should've delete the part of the code that I'm not using, so I am going to edit the original.

Comment: It's best to add a helpful explanation why the OP should remove spaces and non-ascii characters for a complete answer

Comment: @Drakes you are right I am new in stackoverflow thanks

Comment: you make in porra.php un echo ($var); :)

Comment: Removing all spaces and non-asci characters worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The form has the input index set to "Caf**e** da manhã-quantidade-0"

The php script is looking for "Caf**é** da manhã-quantidade-0"

It might be worth using plain ascii to avoid this problem entirely, something like "quantity"

Comment: That was a typo for sure, I changed the code but it's not working still. However, I'll edit the original post to correct that. Ty.

Comment: Try without the spaces. Or replace them with - or _

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action="porra.php">
     <div id="refeicao">
            <h1>Segunda</h1>
        Café da manhã
        <br><input name="Cafe da manhã-quantidade-0" type="number" min="0" placeholder="un." />

        <select name="formato" name="Café da manhã-porcionamento-1">
        <option value="" ></option>
        <option value="un" >un</option>
        <option value="g de" >g de</option>
        <option value="ml de" >ml de</option>
        <option value="fatia de" >fatia de</option>
        <option value="fatia média de" >fatia média de</option>
        <option value="fatias de" >fatias de</option>
        <option value="fatias médias de" >fatias médias de</option>
        <option value="C.S de" >C.S de</option>
        <option value="c.c de" >c.c de</option>
        <option value="copo de" >copo de</option>
        <option value="copos de" >copos de</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<script src="gerar_cardapio_js.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this code, changing only the "action" of the form, but it doesn't work. Not only that, but the value should be inputed by the user of the application, not me.

Comment: no need of chaning action , please change name of inputs

Comment: The error indicates the script is porra.php so no change in action is needed