# js object notation in html input name

Tags: javascript, html

I am using server side javascript with node.js.
Is it possible to make a form input name in html like this:

```
<input name="name.first">
<input name="name.last">
```

to get this js object on server side?

```
req.body = {
    name: {
        first: "firstname",
        last: "lastname"
    }
}
```

Actually I get not the "name" object with children "first" and "last", but:

```
'realname.first': 'firstname',
'realname.last': 'lastname',
...
```

Problem of node.js??

### SOLUTION:

Like Eero Otsus said, I had to set brackets, not a period.
For example:

`<input name="name[first]">`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes it is possible but you need `POST` and `GET` method and a database where to post it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424860/what-characters-are-allowed-in-the-html-name-attribute-inside-input-tag

Comment: You can't make the browser submit the data in that format (from a form submission at least, you can format it however you like with XMLHttpRequest). It's pretty basic data munging to convert it from one of [the standard data formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) though.

Comment: "Problem of node.js??" — Definitely not, since it doesn't include anything that would parse form data that way. You must be using a library. This is why questions are expected to include a [MCVE].

Comment: You either need something on the client side to format the `POST` data into desired format, or a middleware on the server side to do the same. Although I'm wondering how would `name[first]` and `name[last]` work? PHP will format this into an array, but I doubt node.js will OTB.

Comment: node.js will format this too ;) Thanks

Comment: An actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. You should leave your question as it was originally, perhaps with clarification as to the *Question*, but not including an Answer within the Question. Create your own Answer with the code you used. [Answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), when you have solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using node and mongoose. My user controller was fighting with my form. I ended up leaving the form < **input name="name"** > for first and last name inputs. This put them in a "name" array as values 0 and 1. I then changed my controller to
**name: { first: req.body.name[0], last: req.body.name[1] }**. Problem fixed.